# Subscribe to Observable from Retrofit Periodically

Tags: java, retrofit, rx-java

I'm trying to run a REST api call using Retrofit and have it return and Observable but currently I can only figure out how to set it to a delay, but that unfortunately skips the "first interval"

Here I'm trying to get a List of Contacts

```
public interface IContactWebApi {
    @GET ("api/GetContactsByGroup")
    Observable<Groups> getContactsByGroupSync(@Query ("id") String deviceUid);
}
```

And here is where I get the Observable Value using a delay

```
public void syncContacts(String address, String uid, int interval) {
   Retrofit retrofit = getRetrofit(address, true);

    Observable<List<Group>> groupObservable = retrofit.create(IContactWebApi.class)
            .getContactsByGroupSync(id)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .delay(interval, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty())
            .repeat()
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
        groupObservable.subscribe(groups -> handleGroups(groups));
}
```

I've seen some advice suggesting Observable.interval, but I can't seem to figure out how to use that with another interval. The best I've managed to do so far is run it once without a delay, then in the subscribe lamda I replace the observable with one with a delay

```
    Observable<List<Group>> groupObservable = retrofit.create(IContactWebApi.class)
            .getContactsByGroupSync(uid)
            .map(Groups::getGroups)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
    groupObservable.subscribe(groups -> {
        handleGroups(groups)
        retrofit.create(IContactWebApi.class)
                .getContactsByGroupSync(uid)
                .map(Groups::getGroups)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .delay(interval, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty())
                .repeat()
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(groups2 -> handleGroups(groups2));
    });
```

Does anyone know of a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you can just use `interval` with `flatMap`:

```
IContactWebApi api = retrofit.create(IContactWebApi.class);
Observable.interval(interval, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .flatMap(i -> api.getContactsByGroupSync(uid))
        .map(Groups::getGroups)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(groups -> handleGroups(groups));
```